# c# - Can't find iphone on lan

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, network-programming, arp

Me and my roommates are trying to make a system to log when we are home or not,

Since my roommate is using iPhone's and don't want to trow money after developer linces and what not.

we decided to try and make a c# app to check the lan infomation to find connected devices.

So far i been trying to find all of the devices in the ARP cache, but for some reason i can't find any of the iPhone in this, but I can see them on the routers arp cache.

My router is from my ISP. which sadly doesn't allow any kind of API.

Beside this, i tried to ping the devices on different TCP port, but still no luck.

```
   try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_HostURI, _PortNumber);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
```

And sadly now, I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone out there, know how i can check if the devices is on the network. by IP or MAC address.

As always, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IP-Scanner with `Dns.GetHostEntry()`. The return value will contain a Hostname, so you can identify the device. There are many examples on how to create an IP-Scanner and it's pretty easy.

Greetings

Loris

Comment: Well, this has been hanging for quite some time now. sry, work to all energy out of me. But now i tried it. and sad to say. Can't find any iphones. Think they doesn't allowed to be ping by default